# whenever I am going to update a record each time it will create a new entry ( not able to update a record in database)

Tags: java, api

I am developing an API, whenever I am going to update a record by using JpaRepository  method, each time it will create a new entry.
Below are my Entity class,Repository,Service & Controller.

Da_Alert(Entity):

```
public class Da_Alert implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1527460893291554177L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
int alertId;

@Column(name="alertName")
String alertName;

@Column(name="alertDescription")
String alertDescription;
    .
    .//getter/Setter
 }
```

Da_Alert_Repository (Repository):

```
     @Repository
     public interface Da_Alert_Repository extends JpaRepository<Da_Alert, 
       Integer> {

     }
```

Da_Alert_Service (Service):

```
 @Service

 public class Da_Alert_Service  {

@Autowired
Da_Alert_Repository DaAlertRepository;


public List<Da_Alert> findAll() {
    return DaAlertRepository.findAll();
}

public Optional<Da_Alert> findById(Integer id) {
    return DaAlertRepository.findById(id);
}

public Da_Alert save(Da_Alert Da_Alert) {
    return DaAlertRepository.save(Da_Alert);
}

public void deleteById(Integer id) {
    DaAlertRepository.deleteById(id);
}

}
```

Da_Alert_APIController (API):

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/api/v1/alert")
 @Slf4j
 public class Da_Alert_APIController {

@Autowired
Da_Alert_Service DaAlert_Service;

    @PutMapping("/updateAlert/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Da_Alert> update(@PathVariable Integer id, 
    @Valid @RequestBody Da_Alert Da_Alert) {
    if (!DaAlert_Service.findById(id).isPresent()) {
       // log.error("Id " + id + " is not existed");
        ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(DaAlert_Service.save(Da_Alert));
    }
}
```

URL:

```
 localhost:****/api/v1/alert/updateAlert/1    (PUT)
```

body:

```
  {
     "alertName":"update Test allert",
     "alertDescription":"Test"
     }
```

Comment: As an aside, why do you use underscores in your Java code? This clearly goes against coding conventions and standards for the language.

Comment: In addition, variable names should always begin with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `Da_Alert` object that you pass via `RequestBody` does **not** include any ID. Either pass the ID inside the object (better, then you may remove the `PathVariable`), or set the ID inside `update`. Then and only then you will update and not save a new instance

Comment: @Bilbo, if this answers your question, please, mark it as accepted by ticking a checkbox. Other users will find it helpful when searching for a solution

Comment: sure, @igorepst